# android post http app error

Tags: android, http-post

I am trying to get the post get method in the android app, but some how i am getting errors

Bellow is the main files used in the app.

activity.java

```
package com.aaaaaa.httptest;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import org.postandget.R;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HttpgettutorialActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txtvw;
    String text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txtvw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        text = "";

        postData();
    }

    public void postData(){  
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://webhome.com/index.php?id=69887");  

        try {
            // Add your data
            List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", "dataValue"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

            int current = 0;

            while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                baf.append((byte)current);
            }  

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            text = new String(baf.toByteArray());
            txtvw.setText(text);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

main.java

```
package com.aaaaaa.httptest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.postandget.R;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    String text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        text    = "";

        try {
            postData();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void postData() throws JSONException{  
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://webhome.com/index.php?id=79370");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            // JSON data:
            json.put("name", "Heman");
            json.put("position", "Universe");

            JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
            postjson.put(json);

            // Post the data:
            httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            System.out.print(json);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // for JSON:
            if(response != null)
            {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                text = sb.toString();
            }

            tv.setText(text);

        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.postandget"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".main"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

all comments are welcomed, hope i figure this out in mean time..

warnings:

warnings in the following lines

```
--------------------
activity.java

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", "dataValue"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

---------------------
main xml

<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
----------------------

manifest

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

----------------------
```

Comment: You are gobbling up exception not even logging them before doing that and there is no log or description of your error.. please provide some error details if you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error seems due to lines:

```
httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);
```

these are not valid hearder value, you can set like below:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "JSON: " + json.toString());  
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
httppost.setEntity(se);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you are missing `setDoInput( true )` & `setDoOutput ( true )` methods in your code.

Comment: you need to use those methods when you are sending/receiving datas using POST method.